# How to combine a print line into one line with an input line?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.10 and need help to combine a print line into one line with an input line. This is what I got:

```
for day in range (1, 6):
    print("Enter the amount of bugs collected on day", day)
    num_bugs_collected = int(input())
    total_bugs += num_bugs_collected

print("You collected a total of", total_bugs, "bugs.")
```

I need to combine the second and third lines.

Comment: Use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging). i.e. `print(f"You collected a total of {total_bugs} bugs.")`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do that.

```
for day in range (1, 6):
    num_bugs_collected = int(input(f"Enter the amount of bugs collected on day {day}\n"))
    total_bugs += num_bugs_collected

print("You collected a total of", total_bugs, "bugs.")
```